# Apply class to specific data in CSV file

Tags: d3.js

So I'm trying to color-code the lines in my project to my dataset. Here is a sample:

```
Sepal Length,Sepal Width,Petal Length,Petal Width,Species
5.1,3.5,1.4,0.2,Iris-setosa
4.9,3.0,1.4,0.2,Iris-setosa
4.7,3.2,1.3,0.2,Iris-setosa
4.6,3.1,1.5,0.2,Iris-versicolor
5.0,3.6,1.4,0.2,Iris-versicolor
5.4,3.9,1.7,0.4,Iris-virginica
4.6,3.4,1.4,0.3,Iris-virginica
5.0,3.4,1.5,0.2,Iris-virginica
```

There's 3 species and my goal is to style each species with a different CSS class. This piece in my code (taken from Mike Bostock's Parallel Coordinates example) applies a class, but it applies the class to everything.

```
foreground = svg.append("g")
.attr("class", "foreground")
.selectAll("path")
.data(cars)
.enter().append("path")
.attr("d", path);
```

I'm very new to d3.js and if anyone could help me figure out how to color code these lines to their respective species it'd be very helpful.

Link to jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/flyingburrito/nxjesunj/1/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want to set the `class` of each `<path>` using the species name. You can do this when you append the `<path>`s:

```
foreground = svg.append("g")
    .attr("class", "foreground")
    .selectAll("path")
    .data(cars)
    .enter().append("path")
    .attr("d", path)
    .attr("class", function(d){ return d.Species.split("-")[1]; }); // <-----
```

Here I'm passing `.attr("class", ...)` a function that while extract species name of each datum. I use `d.Species.split("-")[1]` because each species name starts with `"Iris-"`.

Here's the result:
[image]